# jQuery 1.6.2 script not working with latest jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to use an auto-scrolling carousel coded for 1.6.2, and it only seems to work with that version, if I use the latest jQuery (which I need for other scripts being used on the page), this carousel script breaks.

Is this an easy fix (something simple that's changed since 1.6.2) ? I've been messing around with this for hours and can't get it to work without plugging in the older jQuery 1.6.2.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.scrollingCarousel = function (options, i) {
        // This handles multiple elements (like a class selector)
        if (this.length > 1) {
            var a = new Array();
            this.each(
                function (i) {
                    a.push($(this).scrollingCarousel(options, i));
                });
            return a;
        }
        var opts = $.extend({}, $().scrollingCarousel.defaults, options);
                var scrollerInterval;
                var autoScrollInterval;

        /* PUBLIC FUNCTIONS */

        /* reInit is a flag that you can pass in case you don't
           want to remove everything during the destroy phase. */
        this.Destroy = function (reInit) {
            var obj = this;
            var reInit = (reInit != undefined) ? reInit : false;
            $(obj).removeData('scrollingCarousel');
            // this removes the flag so we can re-initialize

            obj.children(':eq(1)').remove();
                    if ($(this).find('> div').length > 0) {
                         obj[0].innerHTML = $(this).find('> div')[0].innerHTML;
                            obj.children().each(function() {
                                $(this, obj)[0].style.cssText = '';
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            obj.find('li').each(function() {
                                $(this, obj)[0].style.cssText = '';
                            });
                        }
                        obj.children()[0].style.cssText = '';
                        obj[0].style.cssText = '';
                    obj.unbind();
        };

        this.Update = function (options) {
            opts = null;
            opts = $.extend({}, $().scrollingCarousel.defaults, options);
            this.Destroy(true);
            return this.Create();
        };


                /* CREATE FUNCTION */
        this.Create = function (iteration, method) {


                        // does the object being called exist in the DOM and does it have content? 
                        if(!$(this).html()) {
                            return false; 
                        }
            var obj = this;
            var objContent = obj.html();

            // this stops double initialization
            if ($(obj).data('scrollingCarousel') == true && method != 'pause') {
                return this;
                        }
            // beforeCreateFunction
            if (opts.beforeCreateFunction != null && $.isFunction(opts.beforeCreateFunction)) {
                opts.beforeCreateFunction(obj, opts);
                        }

            //START MAIN CREATE FUNCTIONALITY

                        var scrollerContent;
                        var scrollSwitch = 0;
                        var scrollerPosition;
                        var sMultiplier;
                        var scrollerChildren;
                        var offSetDistance;
                        var scrollDistance;
                        var centerPoint;
                        var functions = new Object();
                        var scrollContainer = obj[0];

                        scrollContainer.style.paddingLeft = '0';
                        scrollContainer.style.paddingRight = '0';

                        var scrollContainerLength = scrollContainer.offsetWidth;

                        var childType = obj.children()[0].nodeName.toLowerCase();

                        switch(childType) {

                            case 'div':
                            if (!method) {
                                scrollContainer.innerHTML = '<div>'+obj[0].innerHTML+'</div>';
                                scrollContainer.innerHTML += scrollContainer.innerHTML;
                            }
                            scrollerContent = obj.children('div');
                            scrollerChildren = obj.children('div:first').children('div');
                            break;

                            case 'ul':
                            if (!method) {
                                scrollContainer.innerHTML += scrollContainer.innerHTML;
                            }
                            scrollerContent = obj.find('ul');
                            scrollerChildren = obj.find('ul:first > li');
                            break;

                            case 'ol':
                            if (!method) {
                                scrollContainer.innerHTML += scrollContainer.innerHTML;
                            }
                            scrollerContent = obj.find('ol');
                            scrollerChildren = obj.find('ol:first > li');
                            break;

                            default:
                            console.log('unable to initialise scroller - please ensure contents are either in a UL, an OL or in DIVs');
                            return false;
                        }   
                        switch(opts.scrollSpeed.toLowerCase()) {
                            case 'slow':
                            sMultiplier = 1;
                            break;
                            case 'fast':
                            sMultiplier = 4;
                            break;
                            case 'medium':
                            default:
                            sMultiplier = 2;
                        }
                        var scrollContentLength = 0;
                        var scrollerHeight = 0;
                        var scrollerWidth = 0;

                        var itemPadding;
                        var itemMargin;

                        switch (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()) {

                            case 'vertical':
                            $(scrollerChildren).each (function(i) {                 
                                scrollContentLength += $(this, obj).outerHeight(true);
                                if ($(this, obj)[0].offsetWidth>scrollerWidth) {
                                    scrollerWidth = $(this, obj)[0].offsetWidth;
                                }
                            });
                            break;
                            case 'horizontal':
                            default:
                            $(scrollerChildren).each (function(i) {                 
                                scrollContentLength += $(this, obj).outerWidth(true);
                                if ($(this, obj)[0].offsetHeight>scrollerHeight) {
                                    scrollerHeight = $(this, obj)[0].offsetHeight;
                                }
                            });
                            break;

                        }

                        if (!method) {  
                            if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') {
                                scrollContainer.style.height = scrollerHeight+'px';
                            }
                            else {
                                scrollContainer.style.width = scrollerWidth+'px';
                                scrollContainer.style.height = ($(scrollContainer).height()>0) ? 
                                                                                                $(scrollContainer).height()+'px' :
                                                                                                $(scrollContainer).parent().height()+'px';
                                scrollContainerLength = scrollContainer.offsetHeight;
                            }
                            if (scrollContentLength>scrollContainerLength) {
                                var offSetPoint = Math.round((scrollContentLength/100)*opts.scrollerOffset);
                                offSetDistance = offSetPoint-(Math.round(scrollContainerLength/2));
                                if (offSetDistance>(scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength)) {
                                    offSetDistance = scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                $(scrollerContent[1]).remove();
                                return false;
                            }
                            scrollContainer.style.overflow = 'hidden';
                            scrollContainer.style.position = 'relative';

                            var itemPadding;

                            scrollerContent.each(function() {
                                $(this, obj)[0].style.position = 'absolute';
                                if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') { 
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.top = '0';
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.width = scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                                else {
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.left = '0';
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.height = scrollContentLength+'px';
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.width = scrollerWidth+'px';
                                }
                                $(this).children().each(function(i) {       
                                    if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') {             
                                        $(this, obj)[0].style.cssFloat = 'left';
                                    }
                                    $(this, obj)[0].style.position = 'static';
                                });
                            });

                            if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') { 
                                scrollerContent[0].style.left = (offSetDistance>0) ? '-'+offSetDistance+'px' : '0';
                                if (opts.looped==true) {
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.left = scrollerContent[0].offsetLeft-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                                else {
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.display = 'none';
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.top = '-1000px';
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                scrollerContent[0].style.top = (offSetDistance>0) ? '-'+offSetDistance+'px' : '0';
                                if (opts.looped==true) {
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.top = scrollerContent[0].offsetTop-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                                else {
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.display = 'none';
                                    scrollerContent[1].style.left = '-1000px';
                                }
                            }
                            obj.mouseenter(function() {
                                functions.startCarousel();
                            });
                            obj.mouseleave(function() {
                                functions.stopCarousel(true);
                                if (opts.autoScroll == true) {
                                    functions.autoScroll();
                                }
                            });
                            obj.mousemove(function(e) {
                                var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
                            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                                cursor.x = e.pageX;
                                cursor.y = e.pageY;
                            } 
                            else {
                                var de = document.documentElement;
                                var b = document.body;
                                cursor.x = e.clientX + ((de.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft) - (de.clientLeft || 0));
                                cursor.y = e.clientY + ((de.scrollTop || b.scrollTop) - (de.clientTop || 0));
                            }
                            cursorPosition = cursor;
                            });
                        }

                        functions.autoScroll = function() {
                            var ivlRate = 40;
                            if (opts.looped==false) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (autoScrollInterval) {
                                clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);
                                autoScrollInterval = 0;
                            }
                            scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition ? scrollerPosition : 
                                                                 ((opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') ? 
                                                                 parseInt(scrollerContent[0].style.left) :
                                                                 parseInt(scrollerContent[0].style.top));

                            opts.autoScrollSpeed = (opts.autoScrollSpeed<1000) ? 1000 : opts.autoScrollSpeed;

                            if ((opts.autoScrollSpeed/ivlRate)<scrollContainerLength) {
                                scrollDistance = Math.round(scrollContainerLength/(opts.autoScrollSpeed/ivlRate));
                            }
                            else {
                                scrollDistance = 1;
                                ivlRate = Math.round(opts.autoScrollSpeed/scrollContainerLength);
                            }

                            autoScrollInterval = setInterval(function() {   

                                switch (opts.autoScrollDirection.toLowerCase()) {

                                    case 'right':
                                    case 'down':
                                    if ((scrollerPosition+scrollDistance)>scrollContentLength) {
                                        scrollerPosition = 0;
                                        scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition+scrollDistance;
                                    }
                                    break;
                                    case 'left':
                                    case 'up':
                                    default:
                                    if ((scrollerPosition-scrollDistance)<(0-(scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength))) {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollContainerLength;
                                        scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition-scrollDistance;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') { 
                                    scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.left = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                    scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.left = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                                else {  
                                    scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.top = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                    scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.top = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                            }, ivlRate);
                        };

                        functions.startCarousel = function() {
                            if (autoScrollInterval) {
                                clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);
                                autoScrollInterval = 0;
                            }
                            centerPoint = (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') ? 
                                                        Math.round($(scrollContainer).offset().left+(scrollContainer.offsetWidth/2)) :
                                                        Math.round($(scrollContainer).offset().top+(scrollContainer.offsetHeight/2));

                            scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition ? scrollerPosition : 
                                                                 ((opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') ? 
                                                                 parseInt(scrollerContent[0].style.left) :
                                                                 parseInt(scrollerContent[0].style.top));

                            scrollerInterval = setInterval(function() {
                                var cursorDistance;
                                var cursor = (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') ? cursorPosition.x : cursorPosition.y;
                                var halfContainer = scrollContainerLength/2;

                                cursorDistance = (cursor<centerPoint) ? centerPoint-cursor : cursor-centerPoint;

                                scrollDistance = (cursorDistance<(Math.ceil((halfContainer/100)*30))) ? 1 :
                                                                     ((cursorDistance<(Math.ceil((halfContainer/100)*50))) ? 2*sMultiplier : 
                                                                     ((cursorDistance<(Math.ceil((halfContainer/100)*70))) ? 3*sMultiplier :
                                                                     ((cursorDistance<(Math.ceil((halfContainer/100)*90))) ? 4*sMultiplier :
                                                                     6*sMultiplier)));

                                if (cursor<centerPoint) {

                                    if ((scrollerPosition+scrollDistance)>0 && opts.looped==false) {
                                        scrollerPosition = 0;
                                    }
                                    else if ((scrollerPosition+scrollDistance)>scrollContentLength) {
                                        scrollerPosition = 0;
                                        scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition+scrollDistance;
                                    }
                                }
                                else if (cursor>centerPoint) { 

                                    if ((scrollerPosition-scrollDistance)<(0-(scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength))) {

                                        if (opts.looped==false) {
                                            scrollerPosition = (0-(scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength));
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            scrollerPosition = scrollContainerLength;
                                            scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition-scrollDistance;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') { 
                                    scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.left = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                    scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.left = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                                else {  
                                    scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.top = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                    scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.top = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                }
                            }, 40);
                        };

                        functions.stopCarousel = function(easing) {

                            if (!scrollerInterval) { 
                                return;
                            }
                            clearInterval(scrollerInterval);
                            scrollerInterval = 0;
                            if (!easing || opts.looped==false || opts.autoScroll==true) {
                                return;
                            }
                            if (scrollDistance>1) {
                                var i;
                                var brakingDistance = 0;
                                for (i=scrollDistance;i>1;i--) {
                                    brakingDistance+=i;
                                }
                                var cursor = (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') ? cursorPosition.x : cursorPosition.y;

                                if (cursor<centerPoint) {
                                    if ((scrollerPosition+brakingDistance)>scrollContentLength) {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength;
                                        scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                    }
                                } 
                                else {
                                    if ((scrollerPosition-brakingDistance)<(0-(scrollContentLength-scrollContainerLength))) {
                                        scrollerPosition = scrollerPosition+scrollContentLength;
                                        scrollSwitch = (scrollSwitch == 0) ? 1 : 0;
                                    }  
                                }
                                var ivl = setInterval(function() {
                                    if (scrollDistance>1) {
                                        if (cursor<centerPoint) {
                                            scrollerPosition+=scrollDistance;
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            scrollerPosition-=scrollDistance;
                                        }
                                        if (opts.scrollerAlignment.toLowerCase()!='vertical') {
                                            scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.left = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                            scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.left = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                        }
                                        else {
                                            scrollerContent[scrollSwitch].style.top = scrollerPosition+'px';
                                            scrollerContent[(scrollSwitch==0) ? 1 : 0].style.top = scrollerPosition-scrollContentLength+'px';
                                        }
                                        scrollDistance--;
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        clearInterval(ivl);
                                    }
                                }, 50);
                            }

                        };

                        if (method != 'pause') {
                            if (opts.autoScroll == true) {
                                functions.autoScroll();
                            }
                        }

            switch (method) {
                        case 'pause':
                        functions.stopCarousel();
                        if (autoScrollInterval) {
                            clearInterval(autoScrollInterval);
                            autoScrollInterval = 0;
                        }
                        obj.unbind('mouseenter');
                        obj.unbind('mouseleave');
                        $(obj).data('scrollingCarousel', false);
                        return;
                        break;
                        case 'play':
                        $('html').mousemove(function(e) {
                                var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
                            if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
                                cursor.x = e.pageX;
                                cursor.y = e.pageY;
                            } 
                            else {
                                var de = document.documentElement;
                                var b = document.body;
                                cursor.x = e.clientX + (de.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft) - (de.clientLeft || 0);
                                cursor.y = e.clientY + (de.scrollTop || b.scrollTop) - (de.clientTop || 0);
                            }
                            cursorPosition = cursor;

                            if (cursorPosition.x>=obj.offset().left && cursorPosition.x<=(obj.offset().left+obj[0].offsetWidth) &&
                                 cursorPosition.y>=obj.offset().top && cursorPosition.y<=(obj.offset().top+obj[0].offsetHeight)) {
                                        functions.startCarousel();
                                }
                                obj.mouseenter(function() {
                                    functions.startCarousel();
                                });
                                obj.mouseleave(function() {
                                    functions.stopCarousel(true);
                                    if (opts.autoScroll == true) {
                                        functions.autoScroll();
                                    }
                                });
                            $(this).unbind('mousemove');

                            if (opts.autoScroll == true) {
                                functions.autoScroll();
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    }   

            //END MAIN CREATE FUNCTIONALITY

            // Set a flag to show that this element has been plugin'd
            $(obj).data('scrollingCarousel', true);

            // afterCreateFunction
            if (opts.afterCreateFunction != null && $.isFunction(opts.afterCreateFunction)) {
                opts.afterCreateFunction(obj, opts);
                        }
            return this;
        };

        this.Pause = function () {
            this.Create(i, 'pause');
        };
        this.Play = function () {
            this.Create(i, 'play');
        };

                // CREATE FUNCTION CALL
        return this.Create(i);
    };

    jQuery.fn.scrollingCarousel.defaults = {
        autoScroll: false,
        autoScrollDirection: 'left',
        autoScrollSpeed: 10000,
        looped: true,
        scrollerAlignment: 'horizontal',
        scrollerOffset: 0,
        scrollSpeed: 'medium',
        beforeCreateFunction: null,
        afterCreateFunction: null
    };
})(jQuery);







    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel( {
            autoScrollDirection: 'left',
            autoScroll: true,
            autoScrollSpeed: 11500
        });
    });
```

Comment: What does the browser console say?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function custom.js:534

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function (index):154
(anonymous function)

Comment: This last bit that calls the function?      $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#carousel-demo1').scrollingCarousel( {
            autoScrollDirection: 'left',
            autoScroll: true,
            autoScrollSpeed: 11500
        });
    });

Comment: you can use $.noConflict to keep older version and latest version.

Comment: Try using jQuery Migrate https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/

Answer (score 0):

jQuery migrate is required to get older versions working with the latest (I think older than 1.9) versions.